# Spring: Dynamic registrations of beans, rest-controllers, and more

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dynamic, module

I am new to Spring and would like to convert my existing applications to Spring Boot.

However, I am using a self-written module framework that allows me to add or remove components or additional functions of the application dynamically at runtime. The whole thing can be compared to plugin frameworks like PF4J or the plugin mechanism in Minecraft servers.

The advantage of this is obvious. The application is much more dynamic and certain parts of the program can be updated at runtime without having to restart the whole application.

Under the hood, a new ClassLoader is created for each module when it is loaded. The ClassPath of this ClassLoader contains the JAR file of the module. Afterwards, I load the respective classes with this ClassLoader and execute there an init method, which contains each module.

Now, I would like of course in connection with Spring that both the dependency injection in the modules functions, and that beans or, for example, rest controllers, which are in the modules, register with the module loading and unregister with the module unloading.

Example: I have a staff module. When I register it, the employee endpoint is registered and is functional. When I unload the module, the employee endpoint is removed again.

Now to my problem:
Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this with Spring, or if something like this is even possible in Spring. Or are there even already other solutions for this?

I also read something about application contexts. Do I have to create a new application context for each module, which I then somehow "closed" when unloading the module?

I hope you can help me, also with code examples.

Answer (score 1):

This post helped me a bit: https://hdpe.me/post/modular-architecture-with-spring-boot/

In short for each module a new ApplicationContext (e.g. `AnnotationConfigApplicationContext`) is created. If you want to share beans between the modules, you have to publish them to the main application context.

Beans can be registered at runtime by `((GenericApplicationContext) applicationContext).registerBeanDefinition(name, beanDefinition);` at the main Application Context.

Another problem is that additional configurations are required, for example for `@RestController` or similar, in order for them to work. See other questions on StackOverFlow from me.

Comment: is it possible to generate a controller from pure functions ? im importing a library/piece of code that is all functions - i want to generate endpoints from these automatically. is there a way to do that ?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe you can use a little bit reflection to retrieve all methods from the given class and expose them as endpoints.